# How to calculate length of unsigned char using C?

Tags: c

i have a question that how to find length of unsigned char?
here is my unsigned char:

```
unsigned char tlv_buffer = "DF04024500DF0C03125050";
```

Pls anyone knows that help me?

Comment: your initialization is wrong.

Comment: Size of unsigned char is 1, by language definition. Its length would also be 1 on any 8-bit non-variable character encoding (with something like UTF8 it could be partial character, and with UTF32 one unsigned char is exactly a quarter of single character.

Comment: @George actually this is a constraint violation  (error by C standard)

Comment: Just change your code to `unsigned char tlv_buffer[] = "DF04024500DF0C03125050";` and call `strlen(tlv_buffer)`, that'll return the length.

Comment: `"DF04024500DF0C03125050"` is not a char

Answer (score 4):

You should initialized like:

`unsigned char *tlv_buffer = "DF04024500DF0C03125050"`;

and then calculate the length using [strlen](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strlen.htm)

`int tlv_buffer_length = strlen((char*) tlv_buffer)`;

or as @M.M point it up in the comments :

`char tlv_buffer [] = "DF04024500DF0C03125050"`;

`int tlv_buffer_length = strlen(tlv_buffer)`;

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
printf("Hello, World!\n");
unsigned  char tlv_buffer[] = "DF0402df4500DF0C03125050";
int length = strlen(tlv_buffer );
printf("Length is %d \n", length );
return 0;
}
```

// just tested. it work

Comment: Good luck running that.

Comment: @staringlizard It just needs to be something that decays into a pointer.

Comment: @George, no, it needs to be a pointer in order to be assigned a pointer type.

Comment: @staringlizard look up array decaying, in this case, it just needs to be anything that will decay into something that will either be a `char*` or will implicitly cast to a `char*`. I think the implicit cast is fine for the op.

Comment: @George, dante just changed tlv_buffer to tlv_buffer[]. You cannot write tlv_buffer = "qwdqweqw" like it was written when I wrote my comment, It just won't work. You can try it yourself.